# Changing font color in each PairGrid Seaborn plot based on pearsonr value:

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting using seaborn and I am using seaborn.PairGrid function (code below).

I am able calculate pearsonr value and set my color list.

Is there way to use to change each pairplot color based on the pearsonr correlation values?

```
global my_colors
my_colors = []

def corrfunc(x, y, **kws):
    r = stats.pearsonr(x, y)[0] ** 2
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.annotate("r$^2$ = {:.2f}".format(r),
                 xy=(.1, .9), xycoords=ax.transAxes)
    if r > 0.6:
       my_colors.append('g')
    elif r < 0.6:
       my_colors.append('r')
    return r

df = pd.read_excel(Inp_Filename, sheetname='IC_Data')

IC_Plot = sns.PairGrid(df)
IC_Plot.map_offdiag(corrfunc)

IC_Plot.map_offdiag(sns.regplot, color='g') 
#Need to change color of each 
#pairplot based on the pearsonr value

IC_Plot.map_offdiag(plt.scatter, s=10)

IC_Plot.savefig("IC_Pair.png")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may call the plotting method from within the function that determines the color. In that way the color can simply be given as an argument to the plotting function.

```
import seaborn.apionly as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

df = sns.load_dataset("iris")

def corrfunc(x, y, **kws):
    r = pearsonr(x, y)[0] ** 2
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.annotate("r$^2$ = {:.2f}".format(r),
                 xy=(.1, .9), xycoords=ax.transAxes)
    if r > 0.6:
       col = "g"
    elif r < 0.6:
       col= 'r'

    sns.regplot(x,y,color=col)  
    return r


IC_Plot = sns.PairGrid(df)
IC_Plot.map_offdiag(corrfunc)

plt.show()
```

[image]